# Ubuntu Splash Screen Background

Tags: boot, themes, plymouth

I am not new to Ubuntu or anything, but I am just wanting to dabble a little deeper into Ubuntu's Inner workings. I was wondering if somebody could tell me how I can set a picture as Ubuntu's Splash Screen Background. I am not talking about Grub. Grub I have already done. I am talking about the screen after Grub. I have been able to turn it from Purple (Ugly) to Black. But since it is Christmas time I would like to be able to set a Christmas background as the splash screen.

I know I can change the color byusing the command 

`sudo gedit /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.script`

Thanks in advance.

[Picture of What I want to change](https://guiodic.files.wordpress.com/2010/05/ubuntuboot.png?w=595)

Answer (score 0):

The screen you are talking about covering the kernel booting messages is generated by plymouth. You can find detailed information about plymouth at the ubuntu wiki. To tweak it have a look at section "Splash Theme".

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth#Splash_Theme

Answer (score 0):

Tested in Ubuntu 18.04 (GNOME).

1. backup and open file in editor (e.g. Sublime):

   ```
   sudo cp /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.script /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.script.backup
   sudo subl /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.script
   ```
2. find

   ```
   # #2c001e --> 0.16, 0.00, 0.12
   #
   Window.SetBackgroundTopColor (0.16, 0.00, 0.12);     # Nice colour on top of the screen fading to
   Window.SetBackgroundBottomColor (0.16, 0.00, 0.12);  # an equally nice colour on the bottom
   ```

   and change to

   ```
   # #597301 --> 0.35, 0.45, 0.00
   #
   Window.SetBackgroundTopColor (0.35, 0.45, 0.00);     # Nice colour on top of the screen fading to
   Window.SetBackgroundBottomColor (0.35, 0.45, 0.00);  # an equally nice colour on the bottom
   ```
3. Repeat after every system update.

I changed my background from purple `#2c001e` [image: purple] to green `#597301` [image: green #597301] in this example. How did I calculate the right values?

- `#597301` is a hexademical color representation: 0x59 red, 0x73 green, 0x01 blue.
- now divide by 255 (0xff):

  - 0x59 / 0xff = 0.35
  - 0x73 / 0xff = 0.45
  - 0x01 / 0xff = 0.00